# how to extract particular elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to extract customer names with "Name" and save it in a variable. Input is any dummy xml

like response variable should have only this

```
        <customer name="Name">John</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Adam</customer
```

used this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="request">
            <customers>
                <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
                <customer name="State">OH</customer>
                <customer name="Name">John</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
                <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
            </customers>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="response">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$request/customers/customer/@name[. = 'Name']"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$response"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `xsl:copy-of/@select` to:

```
  <xsl:copy-of select="$request/customers/customer[@name = 'Name']"/>
```

You probably should also make a few other improvements:

- Drop the unused `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`
  namespace declaration.
- Define your output as XML and indent it via `xsl:output` so it looks good.
- Wrap your output in a root element so that it's well-formed XML.

**Altogether, then, this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="request">
      <customers>
        <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
        <customer name="State">OH</customer>
        <customer name="Name">John</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
        <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
      </customers>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="response">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$request/customers/customer[@name = 'Name']"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <customers>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$response"/>
    </customers>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will yield this output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
   <customer name="Name">John</customer>
   <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
   <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
   <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
</customers>
```

### Update to answer OP's follow-up question

> what if I need like `<customer name="Name">John; Kevin; Leon;Adam</customer>`

Since you've tagged your question with XSLT 2.0, take advantage of `string-join()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="request">
      <customers>
        <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
        <customer name="State">OH</customer>
        <customer name="Name">John</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
        <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
      </customers>
    </xsl:variable>
    <customer name="Name">
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join($request/customers/customer[@name='Name'],
                                       '; ')"/>
    </customer>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Update 2 to answer OP's second follow-up question

> And what if I have multiple names some are repetitive. I need to
>   filter that duplicate elements

Use `distinct-values()`:

```
  <xsl:value-of select="string-join(distinct-values($request/customers/customer[@name='Name']),
                                   '; ')"/>
```

Comment: what if I need like          `<customer name="Name">John; Kevin; Leon;Adam</customer>`

Comment: I will show you, but you'll have to promise to upvote Martin's correct answer here (as I've done) and accept some of the fine answers you've received to the last 7 questions you've asked.  Thanks.

Comment: And what if I have multiple names some are repetitive. I need to filter that  duplicate elements     `<customers>
        <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
        <customer name="State">OH</customer>
        <customer name="Name">John</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
       <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>                         <customer name="Name">John</customer
      </customers>`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a predicate on the `customer` element, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="request">
            <customers>
                <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
                <customer name="State">OH</customer>
                <customer name="Name">John</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
                <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
            </customers>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="response" select="$request/customers/customer[@name = 'Name']"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$response"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```