# how to remove duplicate elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to extract customer names with "Name" and save it in a variable by removing duplicate names as follows. Input is any dummy xml

like response variable should have only this

```
    <customer name="Name">John; Kevin; Leon; Adam</customer>
```

used this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="request">
            <customers>
                <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
                <customer name="State">OH</customer>
                <customer name="Name">John</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
                <customer name="Name">John</customer>
                <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
            </customers>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="response" >
        <xsl:for-each select="$request/customers/customer[@name = 'Name']">
       <xsl:copy-of select="./text()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">; </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$response"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This generates

```
  <customer name="Name">John; Kevin; Leon; Adam; Leon; Adam; John</customer>
```

but is not removing duplicate names

Comment: You have tagged your question as XSLT 2.0: do you in fact use an XSLT 2.0 processor (your stylesheet says "version 1.0")? If yes, you can use the [distinct-values() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-distinct-values).

Comment: If not, then see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Or, if your specific XST 1.0 processor supports it: http://www.exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html -- P.S. I am puzzled why you hard-code a list with duplicates in the stylesheet itself - and then ask how to de-dupe it in the same styleheet.

Comment: @mnvbrtn - If you're using 1.0 only, how can you use a result tree fragment? (Your variable `request` is invalid in 1.0 as-is.)

Comment: Related answer to earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27156422/290085

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract particular elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155914/how-to-extract-particular-elements)

Comment: you can sort by name and use preceding/following to control if the current element is different to the preceding/following